# DataDog error tracing tab is always disabled

Tags: node.js, nestjs, datadog

I'm new in `Datadog`, recently we are trying to integrate `Datadog` in our system. we have use following code in our code:

```
import tracer from 'dd-trace';

tracer.init({ profiling: true, service: 'Our-Service' });
```

We got logs in Datadog dashboard, but we can't see any error logs. if we go to **APM->Services->Our-Service**, error logs tab is disable like following

[error-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2X4k.png)

and if we go to **APM->Services->Our-Service->Traces**, then trying to see error logs, we can see like following:

[error-traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UCcn.png)

Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The (error) traces from APM are separate from the logs from Logging service (app.datadoghq.com/logs). For sending your logs to datadog, see https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/log_collection/nodejs/?tab=winston30
Typically a datadog agent will collect logs from your service.
You can add the spanId to the logs, so that they will appear in your traces -see https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/other_telemetry/connect_logs_and_traces/nodejs/

The error exceptions that show up in the APM error menu are those that are added to spans.